# insert data from csv file to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i want to insert data from a csv file into my mysql database with php. But i dont know what i doing wrong.

This is my php code

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0){
$csv_file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);


$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile)) {
$csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
$csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);

$insert_csv = array();
$insert_csv['id'] = $csv_array[0];
$insert_csv['name'] = $csv_array[1];
$insert_csv['email'] = $csv_array[2];

if(!empty($insert_csv['email'])){
$query = "INSERT INTO contacts(id,name,email)
VALUES('','".$insert_csv['name']."','".$insert_csv['email']."')";
$n=mysqli_query($database->connection,$query);
}

$i++; 
}

fclose($csvfile);

}
```

This is my csv looks like.

```
id---- name ------- email

1 ---- user1--------bla@hotmail.com

2 ---- user2 --------blah

3------ user 3 ------ blah
```

When i run this code my mysql results are

> in email table = ##0.00 "TL")$# en in my name table= also ##0.00
>   "TL")$#;

What do i wrong?

Comment: Not sure if you need to do all that looping and manipulation in php - why not use the native functionality of `LOAD DATA INFILE`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html  You can then test the statement on your database isntance first to make sure it works

Comment: @hans:is that your csv file format?

Comment: not realy i have a excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use MySQL to do the whole loading process with the [**LOAD DATA INFILE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement.

```
if($_FILES['csv']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {
    $query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'] 
    . "' INTO TABLE contacts FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (id, name, email);";

    if(!mysqli_query($query)){
        die('Oops! Something went wrong!');
    }
}
```

If required you can tweak the loading parameters (`FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, `ENCLOSED BY`, `LINES TERMINATED BY`).

Do take note that if you use this approach your temporary file needs to be stored in a place where its accessible by the MySQL server (like `/tmp`).

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I think you should remove the first

```
$data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
```

line, outside of the while loop...

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this as a example  , it should work for you as you want

I think you missed qoutes in "

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contacts(id,name,email)
VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."')";
```

"

```
<?php

    $csv_file = 'C:\wamp\www\stockmarket\test.csv'; // Name of your CSV file with path
    if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
            $data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
             $num = count($data); 
             for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                 $result = $data; 
                 $str = implode(",", $result); 
                 $slice = explode(",", $str);
                 $col1 = $slice[0]; 
                 $col2 = $slice[1];
                 $col3 = $slice[2]; 

    // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase

    $query = "INSERT INTO contacts(id,name,email)
    VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."')";

    $s=mysql_query($query, $connect ); 
         }
       } 
      }
    ?>
```